# How to upgrade a Console app from .net 5 to .net 7 to use DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, ldap, .net-5, directoryservices, .net-7.0

To connect to an [ldap](/questions/tagged/ldap)-Server i want to use [Directory Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols) in a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)-console application.

- The services are available in [dotnet-7.0](/questions/tagged/dotnet-7.0)
- Therefore i need to upgrade from [dotnet-5.0](/questions/tagged/dotnet-5.0)

These are the steps to reproduce:

1. On a console execute these commands
2. `dotnet new console -f=net5.0 -o=ConsoleFiveToSeven`
3. `cd ConsoleFiveToSeven`
4. `dotnet run`
5. Inside `ConsoleFiveToSeven.csproj` change `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>` and save
6. Execute `dotnet run` again. This creates `\ConsoleFiveToSeven\bin\Debug\net7.0`
7. Execute `dotnet add package System.DirectoryServices.Protocols --version 7.0.0`
8. Add the code below
9. Execute `dotnet build`

#### What is the problem?

- Expected: The solutions compiles without a problem
- Actual: Error CS0103 `distinguishedName` and `ldapFilter` and `searchScope` and `attributeList` does not exist in the current context

The docs for [SearchRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchrequest.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-directoryservices-protocols-searchrequest-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-directoryservices-protocols-searchscope-system-string())) contains this constructor

```cs
public SearchRequest (string distinguishedName
       , string ldapFilter
       , System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope searchScope
       , params string[] attributeList);
```

#### Question

To my understanding the following code below should be fine.
What is the problem?

#### Code for step 8 above

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;   
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;

namespace ConsoleFiveToSeven
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SearchRequest search = new SearchRequest(
                distinguishedName = "foo",
                ldapFilter = "foo",
                searchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
                attributeList = new string [] {"cn=foo", "cn=bar", "cn=com"}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely. In C#, `=` to specify parameters by names is invalid. You should use `:`

```
SearchRequest search = new SearchRequest(
    distinguishedName: "foo",
    ldapFilter: "foo",
    searchScope: SearchScope.Subtree,
    attributeList: new string [] {"cn=foo", "cn=bar", "cn=com"});
```

But if you use default order of parameters you can omit their names:

```
SearchRequest search = new SearchRequest(
    "foo",
    "foo",
    SearchScope.Subtree,
    new string [] {"cn=foo", "cn=bar", "cn=com"});
```

Comment: What a silly mistake to make - i could smack my forehead. Works now thanks.